# Integration test various app.config files pass alone but fail together

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, integration-testing

I have a compiled DLL that contains a mathematic algorithm which uses a config file for its setup.  I have several integration tests where each test uses a different config file and runs the algorithm to test various calculations.  The problem is that if I run a single test, it passes.  But if I run them in a playlist or just select "run all" they fail.  The values calculated are incorrect.  It seems that the config file isn't getting replaced each time and I don't know how to correct it.  All of the input and config files are set to copy always and I've verified that they do get deployed into the test directory.
A sample is below:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{

[TestMethod]
public void TestFunction1()
{
    // before running the test, copy the config for this test and rename it to
    // the correct name so the algorithm picks it up
    System.IO.File.Copy("DesiredConfigFile.config", "algorithm.config", true);

    RunTest();
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestFunction2()
{
    // before running the test, copy the config for this test and rename it to
    // the correct name so the algorithm picks it up
    System.IO.File.Copy("DesiredConfigFile_2.config", "algorithm.config", true);

    RunTest();
}

private void RunTest()
{
    var myInput = ReadInputFile("MyInputFile.txt");

    // when the algorithm object is created, it reads algorithm.config
    // to get some constants and whatnot needed for the math
    using (var myAlgorithm = new MyAlgorithm())
{
    // do some set-up
    var results = myAlgorithm.Compute(myInput);
    // verify results = fail
}

}
```

}

Comment: Look like each test is copying the same file. Which is what they fail when run simultaneously. May need to review how that resource is accessed.

Comment: No, sorry... that was oversimplification.  Each test has a config file specific to that test.  I just copy and pasted this for simplicity and forgot to change that part.

Comment: Ok. understood. I am a little confused about the copying of the config file. Why are you renaming a config file to a dll? How is the configuration being read?

Comment: It makes it difficult to help if the information in the question is not accurate. provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. Show how the config file is read/used by the code under test.

Comment: It's a standard config file read by the configuration manager just like any other config file used in a .NET application.  It's not possible to give the actual test/algorithm because it's highly confidential, proprietary information. The typos were my fault, obviously.  But there is enough information here to understand the issue.

Comment: Ok. the config file is loaded at run time when the executable of the test runner runs. In this case it would be for the test project. if the config file is replaces while running the config manager does not automatically reload. You have to refresh it by section `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");` That is the best I can do for now given the limited information provided.